# MySQL 1264 warning from libmysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5

I'm using the `libmysql.dll` library to connect to my database from a 3rd party application (metatrader).

I managed to connect and things are going almost fine.  I use `mysql_real_connect` and `mysql_errno` for connecting and capturing possible errors.  I'm using the InnoDB engine and `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` in SQL mode.

Questions / Doubts:

1. I thought `mysql_errno` only captures errors and not warnings, but I'm getting a 1264 MySQL warning in metatrader (`1264 SQLSTATE: 22003 (ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE)`), however it doesn't say where. How can I resolve this?
2. If I try to manually `UPDATE` or `INSERT` against my database I get no warnings and/or errors.

I would like to know if this is a `libmysql` bug or find out what's going on.  Perhaps there is a specific table/field responsible?

Any pointers?

Comment: Please, show me the way you are connecting to metatrader

Answer (score 1):

check `my.ini`or `my.cnf` if its contain `sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` if so you need to change it to `sql-mode = "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` then restart the SID service.
Hope that will fix the issue for you

Answer (score -4):

I think there is a stored procedure which is defining the range, and, when triggering, is triggering is a not corret way, for example like an error and not like a normal warning. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why downvote? In a situation I've seen exactly what I've wrote; if it's not your case .. why downvote, simply ignore !